# What does $C_\infty(\mathbf R)$ stand for?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, notation

The text says C<sub>b</sub>(**R**) stands for the space of bounded continous functions on R.

Then what does C<sub>∞</sub>(**R**) stand for?

Comment: $C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ would be a more common notation.

Answer (score 2):

It stands for the space of infinitely differentiable functions on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Isn't that C^∞(X)?

So whether it is a subscript or a superscript doesn't matter?

Comment: It's usually $C^\infty(\mathbf{R})$ but sometimes it's written $C_\infty(\mathbf{R})$, as you have it.

Comment: @YORRAY no problem! :-)